# Make this field as final facing an issue in sonarqube code smells?

Tags: sonarqube

I am running my spring boot apps through jenkins sonarqube, where i face an issue in code smell as making a field as final in the custom exception class which extends RuntimeException
Below is my code

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class CustomException extends RuntimeException {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7436800211172984660L;

    private Exception exception;
    private JsonException jsonException;

    public CustomException(Exception exception) {
        this.exception = exception;
    }

    public CustomException(JsonException jsonException) {
        this.jsonException = jsonException;
    }
    
}
```

Here is the sonar code smell issue
[Code smell issue highlighting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFzSd.png)

If i declare as final then the constructor shows compile error as `The blank final field exception may not have been initialized`
Can anyone help me out on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to add setter methods instead of annotations? Maybe code smell trigger is unable to see that excepion can be set after object is constructed.

But also I believe that this is really a code smell that you have multiple properties for different representations of the same data.